# QRScanner code crashes frequently for ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, avfoundation

I am integrating a QRCode scanner in objective c and the main problem is that it frequently crashes on smaller devices and i checked the same on iPhone new series and the code works fine though i got a crash only once. Can some suggest whats the problem with the below code ? Is it something related to thread or the architecture of the device ios7?

Comment: I know not scanners, but looking at the code ... some issues in ```captureOutput```. You call async on main *inside* the loop and also *outside* the loop you call on main if ```detectionString != nil```. Maybe you need to make the *inside* call sync or call the *outside* code in the completion handler just to make sure the order of execution is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is some dependency between the outside and inside code but as written the order can be anything. I *think* the outside must be called only after the user hits OK in the alert?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
    // zzzzzzz
    // dispatch_semaphore_t s = dispatch_semaphore_create ( 0 );
    // __block BOOL f = NO;

    NSString *detectionString = nil;
    NSArray *barCodeTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode];
    
    for (AVMetadataObject *metadata in metadataObjects) {
        for (NSString *type in barCodeTypes) {
            if ([metadata.type isEqualToString:type])
            {
                detectionString = [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];

                // xxxxxxxxxxxxx inside code
                // this happens on main thread
                // at some undetermined time in the future
                // maybe change to sync or figure out how
                // this must be called relative to outside
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:detectionString preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
                                        //button click event
                                        // zzzzzzzzzz
                                        // f = YES;
                                        // dispatch_semaphore_signal( s );
                                        [self stopReading];
                                        [self sendResult:detectionString];
                                    }];
                UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
                                        //button click event
                                        // zzzzzzzzzz
                                        // f = NO;
                                        // dispatch_semaphore_signal( s );

                                    }];
                [alert addAction:cancel];
                [alert addAction:ok];
                [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                 });
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (detectionString != nil)
        {
            // xxxxxxxxxxxx outside code
            // this happens on the main thread
            // it can happen before, after or while the alert is
            // displayed in the inside code
            // I think there is a dependency between outside and
            // inside code ...
            // Everything is done on the main thread.
            // zzzzzzzzzzzzzz
            // dispatch_semaphore_wait ( s, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER );

            // if ( f )
            // {
            //  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopReading) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
            //  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sendResult:) withObject:detectionString waitUntilDone:YES];
            // }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You need to figure out what the relationship between the inside and outside code is. If there is a relationship at all, e.g. inside must complete first before calling outside, then this is your problem.

I know not scanners but just noted that this may cause trouble as I *think* inside must be done before you call outside.

**EDIT**

If my hunch is correct then see the code with the zzzzz's. This is my second edit. The first one just did the xxxxx's to explain what I think is required. The zzzzz's I've added will sync the inside and outside but it is really just a guess - maybe this breaks the code. But at least you can test this quickly.

** EDIT - again **

Ok, I've changed it again. Previously I used a semaphore as that fitted neatly into your code structure, but it is overkill and I've changed it a bit to get rid of the sem and simplify. Anyhow, let me know how it goes.